# iPhone X Launch Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I am trying to make my app compatible with iPhone X requirements and I already have a splash screen showing before my app loads.
Is there a way to do it without using launch screen storyboard? If not, is there a way to reduce display time of launch screen?

Comment: Your two options are a launch storyboard or a launch image. Launch storyboards are more flexible. There is no difference in launch time between the two methods

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, so how could I conform my app to iPhone X compatibility requirements using just the image?

Comment: To use the image you need to add an image [of the right size](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) to your launch image set. A storyboard is a lot simpler and will adapt to any new devices Apple may release

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to reduce display time of launch screen?

The duration of your splash screen showing is the time needed to load the application. Even when you have a image instead of a storyboard.

PS: I would recommend using the storyboard. Like what @Paulw11 said the storyboard will adapt to any other Apple devices.